# Is the mRNA produced constant during time?

Tags: cell-biology, gene-expression, gene, mrna, archaea

I am doing a statistical data analysis of a dataset of P. Furiosus cells exposed to gamma radiation.

For the samples exposed to gamma radiation, I have the values of mRNA produced over time. For the samples not exposed to gamma radiation (reference samples), I do not have the time at which the mRNA has been extracted.

Therefore, I was wondering: under normal conditions, generally, is the mRNA produced constant with respect to time? I thought that maybe the fact that is constant could be the reason for which there are not the values of time.

Comment: If your sample culture is asynchronous, meaning they're at all different stages of the cell cycle, then mRNA production should be consistent over time. However, if you use chemicals or environmental conditions to synchronize the culture, then release it, you'll see periodic production of mRNA for a while until the cells start to gradually slip out of synchrony. For your paper, I highly doubt they synchronized the cells, otherwise they would have clearly mentioned it.

Comment: thank you  @MattDMo but I do not really get the meaning of "consistent over time" ?